# Qt5 duplicate (copy) an executable file

Tags: c++, qt

New to Qt. Kindly bear if this question too naive. 
On Windows OS environmemt, I have Qt Dialog frame application which has "Duplicate" - push button . In the same directory, there is Qt application - (a Dialog widget with close button) A1.exe.  Now, after click of Duplicate button, would like to copy the A1 exe and rename it as  B1.exe (on the fly) in the same directory and execute it.

So, at the end two Qt applications (A1 exe and B2) running till manually cancel it. After brief research, there seems to be 2 optoins to do - QFile copy  or QProcess. or any other method ?  Appreciate any quick (detailed as well) thought!
Thanks

Comment: Why would you do this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MrEricSir: this  for is a proof of concept for a security project. so, it requires this duplication function, where it can create another executable and rename it  on the fly.  it bit unsual requirment :)

Comment: Please do not down vote my question. Already have lost reputation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char name = 'A';
do {
INCREMENT NAME...
} while ( name + 1.exe ) exists...
```

Then do qfile copy from the original to the new file path made in the loop. From therw qprocess is what youre looking for to launch.

Comment: This gives some hints...i.e first copy woth another name and start the Qprocess to run. Will try it.... Cheers!

Comment: I know i dont give the most in depth answers with code or talk about operating systems, but for this i figured you were simply looking for a practical base design approach.

Comment: Have sovled it after some change in requirement. instead of B2 ,C3,D4 now it will be A1,A2,A3 etc.. For that,  count the button clicks. if button click is 2 then it create file A2 and A3  as Mike suggested ( "name +1 "  using File copy).

Comment: the copy part:  QFile::copy("C:\\qt\\A.exe", "C:\\Users\\Documents\\A("+nstring +").exe").  As a next step,   destination path given by user as QFileDialog and got it as QString... having some issue on the second argument of the QFile::copy. Any suggestions may greatly help..

Comment: Create a qstring c\\users\\documents\\a%1.exe and pass the int with .arg (). That will be your destination parameter. The original file path will be the source parameter. From there make a qfile object on the new file after the copy. You can use the exists bool to see or the qfile copy itself is a bool. From there take the needed info for a qprocess and try qprocess start.

Comment: QFile::copy("C:\\qt\\A.exe", destination_name + "\\"+"A("+nstring +").exe"); // some issue

Comment: QString path = QString ("c\\users\\documents\\a%1.exe").arg (your int);

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to assume that you have write access to any location where executables are stored. On most modern operating systems, installing applications requires granting of temporary elevated privileges. On Windows specifically, you simply cannot assume write access to the install location, period. Anyway, you don't need to copy the executable. Why would you? If you think of modifying the executable: sorry, that doesn't work either. You'll have to sign your executables, no matter what platform you deploy to (linux has package signatures too!). Modifications will break things. Just don't.

Comment: Noted your point. aware of this file permission issue. Doing a proof of concept code only not  production code.